# ISNULL Column SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Problem:
The code reads each row and should determine whether it is empty or not.
I want to print out "works" if the column is null. Otherwise, it should not do anything.
Right now it is not working. It is giving me an error that the column does not exist.(the one mentioned in the if statement)

Here is the code.
Code:

```
DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT [Description]  
FROM tblSubViews ts  
INNER JOIN tblViewSubViewJoin tvs  
ON ts.SubViewId = tvs.SubViewId Where tvs.ViewId = 4

OPEN Employee_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN   
if (Description = null)
begin
print 'works'
end
   FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor
END
CLOSE Employee_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor
```

Comment: Why don't you use a set based solution io cursors?

Comment: @Lieven: because the desired result isn't a set?

Comment: @onedaywhen - lol, the *real* query most likely does more than just printing 'works' but with what we know know, this can easily be converted to a set based solution. I'm sure you agree that a set based solution is preferrable to a cursor based one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare to `NULL` using equals, you mush use `ID (Description IS NULL)`

When using cursors it is also necessary to select into a variable:

```
  FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @Description 
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

You would of course need to declare @Description to be of a type appropriate for the column,

Comment: With this it only print out two rows instead of three.

Comment: When I do it without FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @Description it prints out three rows which are null

Comment: and with this FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @Description it only prints out two rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to fetch into inside the loop as well .I suppose you dont get eny debug prints when alues are non null.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is a special value in SQL - actually, it's the **absence** of a value.

Therefore, since it's not a value, you cannot compare with regular means - you need to use the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` methods:

```
if (Description IS NULL)
begin
  print 'works'
end
```

Comparing with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` will give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: I have executed it within the cursor. FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN   
if (Description IS NULL)
begin
  print 'works'
end

Comment: I have tried that as well but it only prints out two rows. When really, it should be printing out three

Answer (score 2):

There isnt a need for a cursor in this situation

```
SELECT 
[Description],
ISNULL([Description]   ,'Works') AS text
FROM tblSubViews ts   
INNER JOIN 
tblViewSubViewJoin tvs   
ON 
ts.SubViewId = tvs.SubViewId 
Where 
tvs.ViewId = 4
```

You could then shorten this down by adding an extra criteria to your WHERE clause that only selects null description columns?

Comment: +1 for using set-based op. This sort of query shouldn't need a cursor to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isnull()` function in your query, according to your logic.

Comment: isnull() prints out one row less than the actually number of rows.